My AOC monitor gets white screen even if it is not connected with the computer with the hdmi
My AOC monitor displays a white screen even when it's not connected to the computer via HDMI. I’ve ruled out a faulty cable by testing with another cable that works fine on a different monitor. Could this be a hardware issue with the monitor itself, or is there something else I should check before considering a replacement? Thanks

First thing that comes to mind is that the polaization filter layer has been removed from the screen because someone mistaken it for a screen protector. But if that's not the case, then the screen is likely defective.
